# Get value of child input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `li` that has a hidden value and I want to get this value

```
...
<li class="list-group-item" id="A1">item name<input type="hidden" class="bssid-val" value="myvalue"></li>
...
```

I thought the following would work, put apparently not.

```
$('body').on('click', '#hook_list li', function(){
    var BSSID = $('this').siblings('.bssid-val').val();
```

How do I get `myvalue`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1. `this` is a keyword. `'this'` is a string. `$('this')` tries to select elements that have tagName of `this`, i.e. `<this></this>`. You should remove the quotes.
2. The target element is the child of the clicked element. So you need to use `children` or `find` method instead of  the `siblings` method.

   ```
   $(this).children('.bssid-val').val();
   ```

Comment: thanks for the comment. The 'this' was a typo, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('body').on('click', 'li', function(){
    var BSSID = $(this).children('.bssid-val').first().attr("value");
    alert(BSSID);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="list-group-item" id="A1">item name<input type="hidden" class="bssid-val" value="myvalue"/></li>
```

If you want a different click selector you can use it , I generalized with only `li`